# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'?

Tags: ros, rosdep, morse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
I am trying to install asctec_drivers so that I can control the quadrotor through ros in morse simulator.

When I try to run the
**rosdep install asctec_drivers**
i get the following error

```
ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below. [1] : 
rosdep version: 0.10.27

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 121, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 279, in _rosdep_main
    return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 335, in _package_args_handler
    val = rospkg.expand_to_packages(args, rospack, rosstack)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 419, in expand_to_packages
    package_list = rospack.list()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 179, in list
    self._update_location_cache()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 171, in _update_location_cache
    list_by_path(self._manifest_name, path, cache)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 68, in list_by_path
    resource_name = root.findtext('name').strip(' \n\r\t') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I would really appreciate if anybody can tell me how to overcome this error
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172606/attributeerror:-%27nonetype%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27strip%27-?/) by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist...

This look like an old rosdep install. What do you get `rosdep --version`?
Install rosdep from apt-get and remove the local install in /usr/local

`which rosdep` shoudl point to `/usr/bin/rosdep`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on 2014-06-02**:
I get 0.10.27.
and when i tried to uninstall it i got the following error
E: Unable to locate package rosdep

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-03**:
That seems to be a recent version. It looks like a bug to me. Maybe due to a misconfiguration, but it still shouldn't crash.